# Element div not allowed as child of element h5 in this context

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following:

```
$compile .= "<h5 data-count='".$acctemmpi.
            "' class='shortcode_accordion_item_title expanded_".
            $expanded_state . "'>" . $title .
            "<div class='ico'><hr class='hr_v'>
            <hr class='hr_h'></div></h5>
            <div class='shortcode_accordion_item_body'><div class='ip'>" .
            $content . "</div></div>";
```

And get the error: `Element div not allowed as child of element h5 in this context.`
I tried to change the inner div with span but after that I've got more errors.
How do I correct this?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with why you think a horizontal rule makes sense as a child of a heading.

Comment: We need more info... you are just concatenating a string here

Comment: You can change h5 to a div element, I guess

Comment: first remove everything from the H5, and see if you still get errors.. Find a better way to structure and style your html, without having those elements inside your h5..

Answer (score 2):

As per `HTML` standards, you can not put `div` inside `heading` elements such as `<h1>` - `<h6>`.

Take a look at [HTML Standards specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)

`Heading` elements only allow `Phrasing Content` as their children.

Learn more about `Phrasing Content` [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content)

Comment: I think you mean `heading` elements which are distinct from the  `<header>` element.

Comment: yes. You are right. I did mean to say `<h1>` `<h2>` etc. Not the `<header>` `tag`

Comment: Maybe your misuse of code markdown is what's causing the confusion. There is a `header` element, and `h1` to `h6` elements, but no `heading` element (or `tag` whatever-it-is).